# Посмішка чи усмішка? Чи є різниця?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

Такі два схожі і водночас різні поняття 
*[усмішка](http://sum.in.ua/s/usmishka)* та *[посмішка](http://sum.in.ua/s/posmishka)*:

*Усмішка* – лагідна, м’яка, привітна. *Посмішка* – скептична, іронічна.

Чи можна вважати ці два поняття взаємозамінними в будь-якому випадку? Чи можемо використовувати обидва варіанти в одному реченні?

Приклад:  *Не вірте моїй посмішці, усмішка – це всього лише рух м’язів обличчя. Я можу встромити Вам у серце ніж, не припиняючи посміхатися."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На це питання лапідарно відповідає сайт [Мова – ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/usmishka-i-posmishka):

[image]

Але більш детально можна подивитися у ["Як ми говоримо"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53407/33175.html) Антоненко-Давидовича:

> Чи таки справді ці слова — абсолютні синоніми, чи між ними є якась
> значеннєва різниця? Подивімось, як користувались цими словами наша
> класика й народна мова: «Нехай мати усміхнеться, заплакана мати» (Т.
> Шевченко); «Я вам з того світа, любі, усміхнуся» (Т. Шевченко); «До
> смерті не забуду його погляду, його усмішки» (О. Стороженко); «Де той
> погляд молодецький, де той усміх веселий?» (Марко Вовчок); «Нічого,
> нічого, ні вітру буйного, ні усміху з неба, нічого не треба» (М.
> Вороний); «А радість уже осміхається то з одного, то з другого віконця
> темним червоним вогником» (С. Васильченко); «І очі сміялись, а на
> губах перебігав осміх» (І. Нечуй-Левицький); «А осміхнулось воно як —
> аж любо глянути!» (з живих уст).
>
> У цих прикладах слова **усмішка, усміхатися, усміх, осміх, осміхатися** стоять там, де мовиться, що **людині весело, приємно, гарно**.
>
> Наведемо тепер приклади з словом посмішка: «Ходили в поле, жали собі хліб і посміхалися злорадно» (М. Коцюбинський); «Раптом Ляля обернулася до рідних і якось криво, не по-своєму посміхнулась» (О. Гончар); «Це... посмішка з мене» (Словник Б. Грінченка).
>
> Не важко помітити, що тут слова **посмішка, посміх, посміхатися** передають відтінок **іронії, сарказму, кепкування чи глузування** з
> когось. У Словнику української мови П. Білецького-Носенка слово
> посміх, що є синонімом до слова посмішка, перекладено тільки словами
> насмешка, шутка. Подібне бачимо й у Словнику мови Т. Шевченка
> Інституту мовознавства АН УРСР, де слово посміх стоїть у тім же
> значенні. Слова посмішка нема в цих двох словниках. Тим часом у Т.
> Шевченка та в інших письменників є похідні іменники від дієслова
> посміхатися: посмішище («Бо на посмішище ведуть старого дурня
> научати». — Т. Шевченко), посміховисько («Робила мій дім
> посміховиськом та метою всяких дотепів». — М. Коцюбинський).

Тобто, ці слова не є синонімами, вони використовуються у різних значеннях.
**"Усмішка"** і похідні від неї - коли людині весело, приємно; **"посмішка"** і похідні від неї - коли хтось з когось глузує, до чогось скептично ставиться.